# Can a probability density funtion have a negative domain?

Tags: probability-distributions, density-function

I've only ever seen domains stretching from $X\ge0$. 
I have a question where:

$F(x)=cx^2$, Domain: $− 1 ≤ x ≤ 1$

When finding value of $c$, would I only need to integrate $0$ to $1$. And does that go the same for $E(x)/$mean?

Comment: Of course he can.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, a random variable can be negative. If you have an associated density function, you have to integrate over the whole image of the random variable, which means in your case, since $f$ is a probabilty density function, that $$1 = \int_{-1}^1 f(x) dx = \frac{2}{3}c,$$
hence, $c = \frac{3}{2}$. Note that because of this we have $c>0$, which is in accordance with the fact that the *image* of a PDF must almost surely never be negative. In this case regardless of $c$ holds
$$E[X] = \int_{-1}^1 xf(x) dx = 0,$$
since the $f$ is an even function. Because of this, it would be sufficient to solve for $c$ via
$$\frac{1}{2} = \int_{0}^1 f(x) dx,$$
as you suggested.

Comment: Got it! However, when describing the second partt, does that mean my upper and lower limits are 1 to -1 in E(X)? In that case, my answer would be 0. Correct? Thanks

Comment: The bounds of the integral, which makes up $E[X]$, are determined by the domain of $f(x)$, which is from $-1$ to $1$. Also, $xf(x)$ is an odd function, since $f(x)$ is an even function. Hence, the expected value is $E[X]=0$, since any integral of an odd function over a symmetric domain is $0$.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer! You're an absolute legend.

Answer (score 1):

It can have a negative domain. And you will need to integrate over the whole domain (from $-1$ to $1$ in this case).